Detect keybpard output from mouse / Detect media keys from mouse

I got a Trust GXT 970 Mouse. It has additional buttons on wich extra actions can be mapped, using the software for windows. Once configured it works without special software on any Windows device. 
I wish to use the mouse on ubuntu 24.04. Normal mouse keys work (lmb, rmb, middle, forward, back, scroll). If I map mormal keyboard key combinations (eg. ctrl+shift+space) it works too.
Something that dos not work are the media-keys. If I read the inputs with python under windows, the events are called `Key.media_next`, `Key.media_volume_up` and so on, so they seem to be standart events.
If I use evtest on ubuntu I get the following avaiable devices (among others):
/dev/input/event10: SINOWEALTH GXT 970 Gaming Mouse
/dev/input/event11: SINOWEALTH GXT 970 Gaming Mouse Keyboard

It seems, that the mouse is recognised as two devices, one for the mouse inputs and one for the keyboard inputs.
If I read out the events for SINOWEALTH GXT 970 Gaming Mouse Keyboard the "normal" keyboard inputs work, but not the Media keys although they are in the list of supported events:
Input device name: "SINOWEALTH GXT 970 Gaming Mouse Keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    [...]
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    [...]
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    [...]
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    [...]
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33

Does someone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.
Edit: If I connect a Keyboard, that triggers the same (media) events it works without a problem.

Here the lsusb information of the mouse, maybe thats helpfull:
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 145f:02b9 Trust GXT 970 Gaming Mouse
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 [unknown]
  bDeviceSubClass         0 [unknown]
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x145f Trust
  idProduct          0x02b9 GXT 970 Gaming Mouse
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 SINOWEALTH
  iProduct                2 GXT 970 Gaming Mouse
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x003b
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              480mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      71
          Report Descriptors: 
            ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     213
          Report Descriptors: 
            ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)


is this stack exchange Q&A of any help?

If i understood the other post correct (wich may not be totally the case, english is not my native language) , it's about assigning a script to an key. I just want the OS to detect that the key is pressed and execute the standard action.

no it's a mouse button watcher script and there are other answers to explore too in the same link. You should be able to translate the page to your native language.

I looked again at the post and links, and I still find only information, about how to add a custom action to an existing key. I just want the OS to detect that the key is pressed, and execute the standart action (eg. increase volume if KEY_VOLUMEUP is pressed, what it can do, because it works if my keyboard sends this command).
